# PHP and Javascript : Multiple Buttons inside a table

Tags: javascript, php, forms, button, onclick

I'm working with PHP, Javascript and MySQL. My goal is to have a button on each row. The button should call the onclick fucntion and href to another page.

My problem with my code -- >  only the button from the first row is clickable...

I'm assuming the Button ID needs to be unique for each button.. What are my options to make all buttons clickable ?

```
// printing table rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><button id='greenbutton' class='small pill green'>$row[0]</button></td>"; 
    echo "<td><img src='/iframe/$row[7]'>&nbsp$row[5]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[4]&nbspmin(s)</td>";     
    echo "<td><img src='/iframe/$row[6]'>&nbsp$row[2]</td>";
    if ($row[3] == 0) {
        echo "<td>Unknown</td>";
        }
    else {echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";}
    echo "</tr>\n";

    // FOR ONCLICK
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "document.getElementById('greenbutton').onclick = function () {";
    echo "location.href = '/user';";
    echo "};";
    echo "</script>";   


}
echo "</table></center>";
```

Comment: Delegate the event listening to the `table`, check the `e.target` within a handler function, and if it is a button, do something.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><a href='/user'><button class='small pill green'>$row[0]</button></a></td>";
```

...will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You're id's of your dom elements should be unique at all time. To achieve this you can add a counter in your while so that all of your button have an id like 'greenbutton1', 'greenbutton2', 'greenbutton3', etc.

```
$cnt = 1;
// printing table rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><button id='greenbutton$cnt' class='small pill green'>$row[0]</button></td>"; 
    echo "<td><img src='/iframe/$row[7]'>&nbsp$row[5]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[4]&nbspmin(s)</td>";     
    echo "<td><img src='/iframe/$row[6]'>&nbsp$row[2]</td>";
    if ($row[3] == 0) {
        echo "<td>Unknown</td>";
    }
    else {echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";}
    echo "</tr>\n";
    $cnt++;
}
echo "</table></center>";
```

In that exemple I didnt add your javascript function into your while loop because it look like the same function for all your buttons. I suggest you add the function only once but bound it with the class selector instead of the id selector like this.

```
// FOR ONCLICK
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "document.getElementsByClassName('myGreenButtons').onclick = function () {";
echo "location.href = '/user';";
echo "};";
echo "</script>";
```

And then add the myGreenButtons class to your buttons in the while loop. You can also use attributes or types selector to gather your dom elements in a more flexible way. Check out theses links for more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/using-javascripts-css3-selectors.html#fbid=FhIuAA6GqpH

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this work great! But now I need this javascript to also update the value in PHP $_SESSION on click. How can this be done in a simple manner?

Comment: Well javascript and PHP are two distinct entities. (client side and server side) You can't update $_SESSION by javascript. You will have to go throught PHP to do that. So I would suggest that you place your table into a html form pointing to some PHP code that will handle the redirection instead of "location.href". Place an hidden input in your form with no value. Then tweak up your javacript so when one of your buttons is clicked, the values you want to updated are place in that input and then you submit the form via javascript. Php will be able to get your values via $_POST and $_GET.